# Why do I get error on "Array to String Conversion"?

Tags: php, arrays, yii, highcharts, yii2

Why do I get error on `Array to String Conversion`?
What may I do to fix that? Thank you.

My current code is:

https://pastebin.com/EyJ7Ggv1

Here is the message error:

[image]

Comment: Look at the line with `drilldown` and you will see what you are doning wrong ;-)  `(` != `[`. And the `drilldown` line is fine.

Comment: this is not a right way to convert array to string.

Comment: The error and the pastebin code don't match...

Comment: `$fakultas` is an array, right? And you try to concatenate that with an int (that gets converted to string silently).

Comment: Well is the code `'$fakultas.($key+1)'` or `$fakultas.($key+1)`? There are issues with both 1. is variables in single quote strings aren't expanded. 2. is you are trying to concatenating the next key to the full array which won't work.

Comment: @JonStirling I have edited the link

Comment: @Jeff yeah $fakultas is an array. I want to concatenate it because I want to make facutly like A1, A2, A3

Comment: I have changed the name same as `drilldown` line. But, still got the same error @JustOnUnderMillions I have edited the link anyway. That's my full code

Comment: did you also remove the `.` ?

Comment: Hopefully you have done this `$fakultas[$key+1]` (`.` removed), you should use an tool like phpstrom with syntax validation!

Comment: yeah I have remove the `.` @Jeff

Comment: yeah I've done like that. Then, I got the message error `Undefined offset: 10`  @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: Yeah, but that is another issue and we can not refactor this here. Maybe remove the `+1` too. I can not see the connection between the index of `$lessthan25` and `$fakultas` here and dont know why `+1` is there. You have to check that. But the first issue `array to string` is fixed, know check the rest.

Comment: I have found the solution. I made the name to be `$fakultas[$key].($key+1)` @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: ..   Great! :-) ...

Comment: Yeah. Thankyou all for helping. I appreciate it so much

Comment: Then post your answer and make it accepted. This is what SO is all about.